# Selenium - click a link/button in javascript popup

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium to test a webapp, for which most of the selenium test cases are already written. I have no idea how it works, I just build the project and go to link provided in the browser and run the test start running and yes all the test are manually written not generated.

I am using ruby, and doing something like this for clicking a link/button in a javascript popup :

```
def methodName()
    clickAndWait("<Id of the link in js popup that I want to click>")
    assertText("<text I need to check>")
end
```

this method is then called in '.test' file, but never works for a javascript popup, for the rest its all good !

help !

Answer (score 0):

Popups a lot of the time are in a different context, either a **frame** or a **window**. When you call assertText, Selenium ignores these. Use the **switchTo** function (not sure of exact syntax in ruby) to switch to the popup before calling assertText

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby maybe we should use like this:
@driver.switch_to.alert.accept